# gulp-jsbeautifier can't beautify SCSS correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, js-beautify

I'm using the [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/http://gulpjs.com/) plugin [gulp-jsbeautifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsbeautifier) to automatically format a project's source-code after a file's content changes.

The plugin is able to format the JavaScript source-code perfectly the way I want, and it's beautiful!

But when I try to extend this functionality to format the SCSS, it changes everything to a single-line file.

This is a SCSS **input *example***:

```
dg-login {

    height: 470px;
    width: 440px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #001d40;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#28bae2, #001d40);
    display: block;

    & > div:not(#compatibleBrowsers) {
        padding: 48px;
        img {
            &#dglogo {
                margin: {
                    top: 20px;
                    bottom: 20px;
                }
            }
            width: 130px;
        }

        input {
            height: 40px;
        }
    }

    #compatibleBrowsers { 
        position : absolute;
        right: 70px;
        bottom: 30px;
    }
}
```

And that's the "formatted" **output**:

```
dg-login { height: 470px; width: 440px; border-radius: 15px; background-color: #001d40; background-image: radial-gradient(#28bae2, #001d40); display: block; & > div:not(#compatibleBrowsers) { padding: 48px; img { &#dglogo { margin: { top: 20px; bottom: 20px; } } width: 130px; } input { height: 40px; } } #compatibleBrowsers { position : absolute; right: 70px; bottom: 30px; } }
```

Unfortunately, I don't want to minimize the SCSS source-code, they do get minimized but on a later step of the build, not of the source-code maintenance.

This is my **.jsbeautifyrc** file:

```
{
  "html": {
    "allowed_file_extensions": ["htm", "html", "xhtml", "shtml", "xml", "svg"],
    "brace_style": "collapse",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_handlebars": false,
    "indent_inner_html": true,
    "indent_scripts": "keep",
    "indent_size": 2,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 0,
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "unformatted": ["a", "span", "img", "code", "pre", "sub", "sup", "em", "strong", "b", "i", "u", "strike", "big", "small", "pre", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"],
    "wrap_line_length": 0
  },
  "css": {
    "allowed_file_extensions": ["css", "scss", "sass", "less"],
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_size": 2,
    "selector_separator": " ",
    "selector_separator_newline": false
  },
    "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc"],
    "brace_style": "collapse",
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "e4x": false,
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_level": 0,
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_with_tabs": false,
    "jslint_happy": false,
    "keep_array_indentation": false,
    "keep_function_indentation": false,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 0,
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "space_after_anon_function": false,
    "space_before_conditional": true,
    "space_in_empty_paren": false,
    "space_in_paren": false,
    "unescape_strings": false,
    "wrap_line_length": 0
  }
}
```

And finally, the watch defined in the **gulpfile.js**:

```
gulp.watch([
     'app/' + project.jsSrcFolder + '/**/*.js',
     'app/' + project.scssSrcFolder + '/**/*.scss'
   ], function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'changed') {
      gulp.src(event.path)
        .pipe(prettify({config: '.jsbeautifyrc', mode: 'VERIFY_AND_WRITE'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(event.path.substring(0, event.path.lastIndexOf('/'))));
    }
  });
```

What it looks like for me is that the `"css"` rules defined on `.jsbeautifyrc` are not being applied to the `SCSS` files, but maybe there can be a misconfiguration from my part. Any help?

Comment: Does js-beautify claim it supports SCSS? I don't think so. This should be a feature request in the GitHub repo.

Comment: @TJ Quoting their manual page: `file_types` Type: `Array` Default value for css: `['.css', '.less', '.sass', '.scss']`

Comment: Oh... So they're trying to apply CSS formatter on `.scss`... Wonder how that's going to work... Did you try raising a bug then (if one doesn't exist already) ?